# Whence “homomorphism” and “homomorphic”?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, ho.history-overview, terminology

Today ***homomorphism*** (resp. *isomorphism*) means what Jordan ([1870](https://archive.org/stream/traitdessubsti00jorduoft#page/56)) had called *isomorphism* (resp. *[holoedric](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3108/jordan-called-isomorphisms-iso-and-homomorphisms-iso-holoedriques-and-iso) isomorphism*). How did the switch happen?

“Homomorphic” (and “homomorphism” as “property of being homomorphic”) are e.g. in de Séguier ([1904](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?36.0187.02), [pp. 65–66](https://archive.org/stream/thoriedesgroup00sguoft#page/65)) and the last edition of Weber ([1912](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?43.0143.01), [p. 195](https://books.google.com/books?id=5vDuAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA195&dq=Homomorphismus)). “Homomorphism” as map of groups is e.g. in Schur ([1924](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?50.0293.02), [p. 192](https://books.google.com/books?id=I_gY2dTnDXwC&dq=Homomorphismus)). But none of these sound like a first.

I asked this on [hsm](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/whence-homomorphism-homomorphic) a week ago, but got no answer there.

Comment: Remark: the [earliest uses](http://jeff560.tripod.com/h.html) site says 1935, but even in English this is predated by Pontrjagin ([1934, p. 362](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1503168)), Tucker ([1933, p. 196](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1503105)), and for algebra homomorphisms, Levitzki ([1932, p. 382](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1503062)).

Comment: People were still using _isomorphism onto_ and _isomorphism into_ for surjective resp. injective homomorphisms, for far too long (IMHO). I've always found this weird, but I guess they were just not up to date with the change terminology.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Indeed, e.g., van der Waerden’s *Moderne Algebra* ([1930, p. 32](https://books.google.com/books?id=8DKbBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=Homomorphismus)) still laments the absence of stable terminology.

Comment: Note that in the linked paper by Jordan, "group" means "permutation group", i.e., something which more or less means a set endowed with a subgroup of its group of permutations. Isomorphic means isomorphic as groups (not as permutation group). In particular when he says "Problem: determine all groups isomorphic to a given group $G$", it more or less means "classify all (faithful) actions of $G$ [the underlying group, in the modern sense]".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found this footnote on page 195 of Fricke and Klein's [Vorlesungen über die Theorie der automorphen Functionen](https://archive.org/details/vorlesungenber01fricuoft) (1897):

[image]

Translation:

> The term "homomorphic" seems more appropriate than the previously$^\ast$ used "isomorphic", because it refers not to "equality" but to "similarity" of two groups. The term "isomorphism" will therefore from now on be used in the sense of "1-to-1 homomorphism".

$^*$l.c. = loco citato — this seems to refer to Fricke and Klein's [Vorlesungen über die Theorie der elliptischen Modulfunctionen](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ZQLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA138&dq=Isomorphismus) (1890).

Comment: Thank you. I now see that Frobenius ([1902](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?33.0145.01), [p. 456](https://books.google.com/books?id=T01QAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA456&dq=homomorph)) and de Séguier ([1902](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?33.0146.03), [p. 257](https://books.google.com/books?id=o20_AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA257&dq=homomorphe)) also credit Felix Klein — despite Bourbaki ([1981, p. VIII.462](https://books.google.com/books?id=9q8xDGbjHckC&pg=RA1-PA38&dq=morphisme+Frobenius)) attributing the word to Frobenius.

Comment: Moreover Frobenius points to Math. Ann. 41 ([**1892**](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044102918109;view=1up;seq=329)) where papers of (Klein’s student) [Ritter](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?24.0391.03) and [Fricke](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?24.0395.01) already make the switch, attributing it to Klein in his lectures: pp. [22](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044102918109;view=1up;seq=36), [466](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044102918109;view=1up;seq=488).

Comment: So "isomorphism" meant "injective homomorphism"?